# How to compare or lookup specific values from two lists in ansible and print

Tags: list, ansible, jinja2

How to compare two lists in ansible and print desired output below, i have looked other posts in stackoverflow regarding comparing/lookup list , but the way i want desired output is a bit different, unable to figure out the logic to get this working. Please point me to any post that can help me.Thanks

List1:

```
[
    {
        "DES": "server1",
        "PORT": "E46",
    },
    {
        "DESCRIP": "server2",
        "PORT": "E47",
    },
    {
        "DESCRIP": "server3",
        "PORT": "E4",
    },
    {
        "DESCRIP": "server4",
        "PORT": "E7",
    }
]
```

List2:

```
[
        {
            "INTERFACES": [
                "E6",
                "E8",
                "E9",
                "E10",
                "E11",
                "E12",
                "E13",
                "E14",
                "E27",
                "E28",
                "E37",
                "E43",
                "E44",
                "E45",
                "E46",
                "E47"
            ],
            "VLAN_ID": "17"
        },
        {
            "INTERFACES": [
                "E7",
                "E10",
                "E11",
                "E12",
                "E13",
                "E14",
                "E27",
                "E28",
                "E45",
                "E46"
            ],
            "VLAN_ID": "16"
        }
    ]
```

desired output:

If list1 `PORT` value matches/present in list2 `INTERFACES` then print something like this: `server1 E46 has: VLAN_ID: 17 ; VLAN_ID: 16` or `server2 E47 has: VLAN_ID: 17 ; NO VLAN_ID: 16`

If list1 `PORT` value dosen't matches/present in list2 `INTERFACES` then print something like `server3 E4 has NO VLAN_ID: 17 NO VLAN_ID: 16`

below is full desired print:

```
server1 E46 has: VLAN_ID: 17 ; VLAN_ID: 16
server2 E47 has: VLAN_ID: 17 ; NO VLAN_ID: 16
server3 E4 has: NO VLAN_ID: 17 ; NO VLAN_ID: 16
server4 E7 has: VLAN_ID: 16 ; NO VLAN_ID: 17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        srv_id: "{{ srv_id|d({})|combine({item.DESCRIP: _id}) }}"
      loop: "{{ List1 }}"
      vars:
        _id: "{{ List2|
                 selectattr('INTERFACES', 'contains', item.PORT)|
                 map(attribute='VLAN_ID')|
                 list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  srv_id:
    server1: ['17', '16']
    server2: ['17']
    server3: []
    server4: ['16']
```

<sup>(Formatting should be trivial.)</sup>

Comment: thank you Vladimir, your answer worked